# Node.js Stream Error: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'end'

Tags: node.js

Hullo Stackoverflow Gurus!

I have been stuck on this problem where I try to do smething  very simple, I just want to get a website HTML in streams and print it to console.

I get the HTML But I also get an error for some reason:

stream.js:66
    dest.end();
         ^
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'end'

Please checkout my code, just hit run and you will see the same error:
http://runnable.com/UXW8Hg_t3PpsAABh?

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement the end function as well.

```
CustomStream.prototype.end = function() {};
```